# Can this be proved purely on base of UMP?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-groups

Let $A,B$ be abelian groups and let $P$ serve as a product 
with projections $p_{A}:P\rightarrow A$ and $p_{B}:P\rightarrow B$.

Let $C$ be an abelian group and let $f:C\rightarrow A$ and $g:C\rightarrow B$
be grouphomomorphisms.

Then there is a unique grouphomomorphism $h:C\rightarrow P$
with $f=p_{A}\circ h$ and $g=p_{B}\circ h$.

Now let it be that $c\in C$
with $f\left(c\right)=0_{A}$ and $g\left(c\right)=0_{B}$. Can I
conclude from this that $h\left(c\right)=0_{C}$?

I know that the
answer is 'yes', but to prove it I see myself forced to look at the
specific product $A\times B$ having ordered pairs $\left(a,b\right)$
as elements and the maps $\left(a,b\right)\mapsto a$ and $\left(a,b\right)\mapsto b$
as projections. Working with that product it is obvious that $c$
is sent to $\left(0_{A},0_{B}\right)$ and $S$ and $A\times B$ are
isomorphic as products. My question is:

> Is there a way to prove this without looking at a constructed product,
>   but merely on base of the universal mapping property of products?

Comment: Yes; the product projections are jointly monic.

Comment: @Zhen: This is a reformulation of the claim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$c$ corresponds to a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to C$ such that $\mathbb{Z} \to C \to A$ and $\mathbb{Z} \to C \to B$ are zero. Therefore, it suffices to prove (and this holds in any category with zero morphisms):

If $f : D \to A$ and $g : D \to B$ are zero, then the same is true for $(f,g) : D \to A \times B$. The reason is simply that the zero homomorphism satisfies the definition of this morphism, i.e. that we get back $f$ and $g$ when we compose with the projections.